# How to increase index row maximum size in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, index, gist-index

I want to perform KNN on 512-dimensional vector using the solution suggested [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/163915/revisions).

1. I couldn't create table with 512-d cube array. Solved by changing the `CUBE_MAX_DIM` in the source code.
2. Couldn't create index on table with dimensions > 200. Set `block_size=32`. Now works with `dimensionality<=510`.
3. Got new error after changing `block_size` and trying to create index on table with 512-d vectors `ERROR:  index row requires 8208 bytes, maximum size is 8191`

Is it possible to increase this limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would require significant changes, and I doubt it can be done easily.

See these excerpts from `src/include/access/itup.h`:

```
/*
 * Index tuple header structure
 *
 * All index tuples start with IndexTupleData.  If the HasNulls bit is set,
 * this is followed by an IndexAttributeBitMapData.  The index attribute
 * values follow, beginning at a MAXALIGN boundary.
 *
 * Note that the space allocated for the bitmap does not vary with the number
 * of attributes; that is because we don't have room to store the number of
 * attributes in the header.  Given the MAXALIGN constraint there's no space
 * savings to be had anyway, for usual values of INDEX_MAX_KEYS.
 */

typedef struct IndexTupleData
{
    ItemPointerData t_tid;      /* reference TID to heap tuple */

    /* ---------------
     * t_info is laid out in the following fashion:
     *
     * 15th (high) bit: has nulls
     * 14th bit: has var-width attributes
     * 13th bit: AM-defined meaning
     * 12-0 bit: size of tuple
     * ---------------
     */

    unsigned short t_info;      /* various info about tuple */

} IndexTupleData;               /* MORE DATA FOLLOWS AT END OF STRUCT */
[...]

/*
 * t_info manipulation macros
 */
#define INDEX_SIZE_MASK 0x1FFF
#define INDEX_AM_RESERVED_BIT 0x2000    /* reserved for index-AM specific
                                         * usage */
#define INDEX_VAR_MASK  0x4000
#define INDEX_NULL_MASK 0x8000
```

The limit you are hitting is `INDEX_SIZE_MASK`, and to increase it, you'd have to change the tuple header so that `t_info` has more than two bytes.

Perhaps it is as simple as that, but it might have repercussions in other parts of the code.

Comment: I am using Postgres v10.5. 13th bit of `t_info` is unused in this version. I just changed `INDEX_SIZE_MASK` to `0x3FFF` so 13th bit can be used for the size and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Fine, but that way you are barring your way to a PostgreSQL upgrade. Are you sure?